# PHP Object Unserializing: Must the Class definition remain identical between serializing and unserializing?

Tags: php, oop, serialization

A question occured to me after reading [Does PHP serialize Object Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571080/does-php-serialize-object-methods/6571096#6571096)

And especially the statement from 'BoltClock's a Unicorn'

> This of course assumes you have the exact same class definition at the
>   time of unserialization

1. Is this mandatory?
2. What if I intentionaly want to 'update' a Class definition with improved methods?

I assume that I can still unserialize using the new Class definition as long as the changes to the Class definition are purely in the Methods and that the expected Properties still exist.

3. What happens if the new Class definition has new Properties that did not exist in the old definition before serializing?
4. Are they simply filled with zeros when unserialising an string serialized from an old Class definition?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try it?

```
class a{
  protected $p = 420;
  public function m(){ }
}

$s = serialize(new a());
apc_set('s', $s);
```

Then change your class definition and `unserialize(apc_fetch('a'));`

Methods are not serialized, as you read in the linked answer, so adding or removing methods doesn't affect unserialization. Properties are kept as long as they are public, or they are protected/private and exist in the modified class